# Spinner dropdown visual bug in EMUI (Huawei, Honor)

Tags: android, react-native

I created a custom style for spinner dropdown, but I have a visual problem with EMUI layer (Huawei, Honor).

[image: Honor Lite 9]

I test in Samsung A8 (8.0), Xiaomi Redmi Note 3 (6.0), Samsung A50 (9.0), Moto E3 (8.0) and different simulators and dropdown is ok.

[image: Others devices]

Can I resolve this problem without java code? ( I'm using react-native ) Thanks!

This is my code:

> styles.xml

```xml
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_screen</item>
        <!-- Associate picker theme -->
        <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/SpinnerDropDownItem</item>
    </style>
    <!-- Picker Item -->
    <style name="SpinnerDropDownItem" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">15dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">15dp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/muli_regular</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/picker_divider</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

> picker_divider.xml

```xml
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/dark" />
    <corners android:radius="0.5dp" />
    <stroke
        android:color="#363633"
        android:width="0.1dp" />
</shape>
```